# Create Login form in zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to create login page in zend framework2. I have created its view,controller,model and form. Even i m not getting any error.

following my code :

My model as Login.php is :

```
class Login implements InputFilterAwareInterface
 {
     public $id;
     public $username; 
     public $password;
      protected $inputFilter;

     public function exchangeArray($data)
     {
         $this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
         $this->username = (!empty($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : null;
         $this->password  = (!empty($data['password'])) ? $data['password'] : null;
     }
      public function getArrayCopy()
     {
         return get_object_vars($this);
     }

      public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
     {
         throw new \Exception("Not used");
     }

     public function getInputFilter()
     {
         if (!$this->inputFilter) {
             $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'id',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'Int'),
                 ),
             ));

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'username',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'password',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
         }

         return $this->inputFilter;
     }
 }
```

My LoginForm is :

```
namespace Application\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;

 class LoginForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct($name = null)
     {
         // we want to ignore the name passed
         parent::__construct('tbluser');

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'id',
             'type' => 'Hidden',
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'username',
             'type' => 'Text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => '',

             ),
             'attributes' => array(
                 'id' => 'username',
                 'class'=>'',
                 'autocomplete'=>'OFF',
                 'max'=>'100',
             ),
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'password',
             'type' => 'Text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => '',
             ),
             'attributes' => array(
                 'id' => 'password',
                 'class'=>'',
                 'autocomplete'=>'OFF',
                 'max'=>'100',
             ),
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'submit',
             'type' => 'Submit',
             'attributes' => array(
                 'value' => 'Login',
                 'id' => 'login',
                 'class'=>'btn btn-success',
             ),
         ));


     }
 }
```

and my controller action code is :

```
public function indexAction() 
    {

    $form = new LoginForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $user=new LoginTable();
           if ($request->isPost()) {
             $login = new Login();
             $form->setInputFilter($login->getInputFilter());
             $form->setData($request->getPost());
              if ($form->isValid()) {
                 $data=$login->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                 $user->getUser($this->$username,$this->$password);
                  if($user){    
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
                 'action' => 'album'));
                    }else{
                    return array('form' => $form);
                    }              
             }

         }

         return array('form' => $form);




    }
```

my form is not validating at this statement "if ($form->isValid()){}" the exicution is not entering in this statement. I searched out every thing but not able to find solution what i m missing. Can any body help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the form it looks as if you have an input filter attached to the hidden field `id`. If you are looking to register the user you obviously will not have their `id` before authentication.

You can test this by adding a `else` statement of your form and checking the forms messages (because the element is hidden you will not see it output otherwise)

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
   // Is valid code here
} else {
   print_r($form->getMessages());
}
```

This will probably output and array with the message "id - this element cannot be empty" or something similar.

The solution would be to remove the `id` input filter from the form (and probably the `id` form element as I can't see how this would be needed).

Comment: thanks a lot sir you really get me out from a big headache.. its working.